# asp.net placeholder 'page' does not contain a definition of 'PlaceHolder'

Tags: asp.net

I'm having difficulty with my asp.net aplication, the problem is that I can not compile my application because it marks an error.  There is no placeholder which is in a page

my page

```
...other...
<tbody>            
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phChange" />
</tbody>
...other...
```

in code behind

```
ucontrol = (UserControlChange)LoadControl("~/ui/UserControlChange.ascx");
        ucontrol.Data= data;
        this.phChange.Controls.Add(ucontrol);
```

but when I run ignoring the error, it works perfectly.

This is very frustrating that every execution make the mistake, and when I have an error really, sent to a version that does not generate a good bug report, only shows the ugly yellow page with the error line.

What I can do?

Comment: What is the exact error and stack trace?

Comment: I don't see `admin_criteria` or `phCriteria` in the code you've provided...

Comment: Ups, the problem is in two pages, which basically copy and have the same behavior, but for different entities, one contain "phChange" and the other "phCriteria"